# Cloned git not in Docker Volume?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I use the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos
VOLUME ["apitests"]
RUN su
RUN yum -y install git
RUN git clone https://github.com/Human-Connection/CUBE-arduino-yun.git /apitests/
```

then I build my image

```
docker build -t apitesting .
```

and start a container with a shell

```
docker run -ti apitesting /bin/bash
```

Now I find /apitests within the container.
But I cannot find the cloned git data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define the `VOLUME` after the data is there. Docker auto populates a `VOLUME` with whatever is in the image. At the beginning `/apitests` is empty.

```
FROM centos
RUN yum -y install git
RUN git clone https://github.com/Human-Connection/CUBE-arduino-yun.git /apitests/
VOLUME ["apitests"]
```

Also, `RUN su` as it's own step does nothing. Each `RUN` launches in it's own container. The only thing that carries over between `RUN` steps is what is written to disk and subsequently committed to the image layer.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me: Define the volume after the creation + loading of data in your directory.

```
FROM centos
RUN yum -y install git
RUN mkdir /apitests
RUN git clone https://github.com/Human-Connection/CUBE-arduino-yun.git /apitests/
VOLUME /apitests
```